Name of a Capacitated VRP variant
I'm looking into a routing problem that feels like it should have received some attention, though I can't seem to find the right keywords to search for it. Conceptually, you might think of it as "TSP with fuelling stops" or something along those lines.
A bit more formally, we can describe the problem as follows: let $V = \{d, r_1, \ldots, r_m, c_1, \ldots, c_n\}$ be the vertex set consisting of a depot $d$, $m$ recharge points $r_j$ and $n$ customers $i$. Let $D(u,v)$ be the $u\to v$ distance and let $K$ be a number that indicates capacity. Then, the objective is to find the shortest $d\to d$ route that visits each customer $c_i$ exactly once and any number of recharge points $r_j$ any number of times, such that the total length of every route segment $x\to\ldots\to y$ with $x,y\in \{d, r_1, \ldots, r_m\}$ is at most $K$.
Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

This "green vehicle routing problem" (GVRP) was introduced in 2012:

Erdoğan, S., & Miller-Hooks, E. (2012). A green vehicle routing problem. Transportation research part E: logistics and transportation review, 48(1), 100-114.

Google Scholar returns three recent review articles from 2021 and 2022.

Great, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!
